# Bash script to automate multiple subtitle into video mp4 container files

Tags: bash, find

First off - I am no programmer or scripter - just what I've been playing around with for a few days.

I've got a folder containing mp4 video files and srt subtitle files. I've managed manually to re-encode using mencoder and handbrake to hardcode the subtitles into the video files.

```
mencoder -oac pcm -ovc raw -sub NAMEOFVIDEO.sub -utf8 -o NAMEOFVIDEO_SRT NAMEOFVIDEO.mp4
```

This works well and is what i'm looking for. So what I have is this /working directory with multiple .srt and .mp4 ( there maybe 2 or 3 new video and srt files each day )

I can manage if there is only 1 .srt and 1 .mp4 file BUT I'm trying to figure out how I can create a Bash script that can run the mencoder command if I have 2 or 3 different srt and mp4 files as the mencoder line has to run with the correct corresponding srt file and mp4 file combination.

All I can come up with is something like `mp4_file= find \working -type f -name "*.mp4" | head -1` which finds the first result .mp4

`srt_file = find \working -type f -name "*.srt" | head -1`which finds the first result .srt ( Luckily it's the same basename file )

then run the variables through the mencoder command, `mencoder -oac pcm -ovc raw -sub $srt_file -utf8 -o $mp4_file-SRT $mp4_file` but as I expressed if there are more than 1 combinations of files ( a loop maybe ) then I have to stick the output through `HandBrakeCLI --preset "High Profile" -i $mp4_file-SRT -o $mp4_file`

It's horrible and I'm missing some easier way to do this?

Comment: While Olaf's solution looks like a good answer, we're left to guess if it will really solve your problem. It will be easier to provide a meaningful answer if you can edit your post to include sample input, and required output, with sample input including 1 of all the cases you have identified as std and special and the output including  those cases transformed as needed. You can type your sample data in 1 per line, select the whole block of data, then use the {} reformat tool to keep the 1 item per line formatting in your post. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the same basename, you can do it with `find` and a loop:

```
find /working -type f -name '*.mp4' | while read mp4; do
    b=`basename $mp4 .mp4`
    d=`dirname $mp4`
    mencoder -oac pcm -ovc raw -sub $d/$b.sub -utf8 -o $mp4-SRT $mp4
done
```

If the mp4 and sub files have different names or are in different directories, this will not work of course.